# Why does the half time decrease in a 0th order reaction?

Tags: kinetics

A --> B

rate = k

Half time = [A]<sub>0</sub>/2k

From the half time equation, since there are no variables, i don't see how the half time of a 0th order reaction can change? It's dependent on the initial concentration of A, which is constant, so how can the half time be decreasing as shown in the graph below.

[image]

The only explanation I can imagine is that A<sub>0</sub> is not the initial concentration at the start of the reaction, but the concentration at each the start of each half time.

Comment: A half life time is a property of a first order reaction. You are misapplying the concept.

Answer (score 2):

For the first half life(say,$T^1_{\frac{1}{2}}$ )and the second half life(say, $T^2_{\frac{1}{2}}$) the initial concentrations of the reactant to be used for calculating are different. 
For, the $0$th order reaction $\ce{A -> B}$, the integrated rate equation will be, $$\ce{[A]_t = [A]_0 - kt}$$ where $k$ is the rate constant.
So, at the first half life($t$ = $T^1_{\frac{1}{2}}$), $\ce{[A]_t = \frac{[A]_0}{2}}$, So, we have $T^1_{\frac{1}{2}}$= $\frac{[A]_0}{2k}$ 
But for the second half life ($t$ =  $T^2_{\frac{1}{2}}$),  $\ce{[A]_t^, = \frac{[A]_0}{4}}$ and $\ce{[A]_0^' = \frac{[A]_0}{2}}$, Putting these values in the equation, we have $T^2_{\frac{1}{2}}$ = $\frac{[A]_0}{4k}$
 Thus we can see that for any $nth$ half life in a $0$ th order reaction, the $[A]_0$ which we are habituated to use in $1st$ half life is not the initial concentration(i.e. at $t=0$) but for the nth half life, $[A]_0$ is the concentration of the reactant after completion of $n-1$ half lives i.e $\frac{[A]_0}{2^{n-1}}$, and thus using this fact a general formula for nth half life (i.e. $T^n_{\frac{1}{2}}$) in ) $0$ th order reaction will be  $\frac{[A]_0}{2^nk}$.